# How can i Incremental Saving in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, export

i wanna save the illustrator file automatically using actions, i used the F1 to automatically save the file in a folder but the file is overwritten.

My question is how can i change the filename without pressing 1 2 3
i mean the output should be
FileName___1.ai (version 1 )
FileName___2.ai (version 2 )
FileName___3.ai (version 3 )

The original file name is FileName.ai

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this free plugin from Astute Graphics? It allows you to do what you've described and more.

https://astutegraphics.com/plugins/autosaviour